# Announcer, booster, publicist badge pages: Link to migrated question

Tags: feature-request, migration, publicity-badges

I want to suggest that on the pages that show the users that have achieved the badges of [announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/260), [booster](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/261) and [publicist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/262), instead of displaying "Post is no longer available", the text "This questions has been migrated to [another stackexchange site](http://link.to/migrated/question)" be shown instead, and with the appropriate link to the question's new location.